# How to check the state of a view in React Native?

Tags: mobile, react-native, jsx

I am trying to update the `backgroundColor` of a view on a button press. If the colour is red then I want it to change to orange and vice versa.

I currently have the button changing the view from red to orange, but not the other way around.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        viewColour: "red",
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.parentView}>
            <Button
                title="Press here"
                onPress={() => this.setState({viewColour:"orange"})}
            />

            <View style={Object.assign({}, styles.colourSquare, {backgroundColor: this.state.viewColour})}/>
        </View>
    );
}
```

How can I check what the current colour of the view is in order to determine what colour to change it to when pressing the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do

```
render() {
return (
    <View style={styles.parentView}>
        <Button
            title="Press here"
            onPress={() => this.setState({viewColour: this.state.viewColour == 'red' ? "orange" : 'red'})}
        />

      <View style={[styles.colourSquare, {backgroundColor: this.state.viewColour}]}/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While Mohammed's method is valid Facebook now recommend passing a function to setState instead of an object when the new state depends on the old state [(according to the docs)](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate). Therefore you should do `this.setState((prevState) => ({viewColour: prevState.viewColour == 'red' ? "orange" : 'red'}))`